# Google Maps AutoComplete and Directions with fixed destination and variable origin

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, directions

I am using GoogleMaps with AutoComplete and Directions services to draw a route between two markers (places). The example on google maps documentation has two input fields, one for origin and other for destination. I have destination LatLong. How can I fix the destination with these latLong and draw route when user selects origin.

destination lat/lng: `latitude: 25.116810, longitude: 55.123562`

link to jsfiddle [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waqarakbar/wwspbxme/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .controls {
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #origin-input,
      #destination-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 200px;
      }

      #origin-input:focus,
      #destination-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      #mode-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #mode-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter an origin location">

    <input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a destination location">

    <div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
      <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
      <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
      <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>
    </div>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          mapTypeControl: false,
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13
        });

        new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
      }

       /**
        * @constructor
       */
      function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
        this.map = map;
        this.originPlaceId = null;
        this.destinationPlaceId = null;
        this.travelMode = 'WALKING';
        var originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
        var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination-input');
        var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');
        this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            originInput, {placeIdOnly: true});
        var destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            destinationInput, {placeIdOnly: true});

        this.setupClickListener('changemode-walking', 'WALKING');
        this.setupClickListener('changemode-transit', 'TRANSIT');
        this.setupClickListener('changemode-driving', 'DRIVING');

        this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
        this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');

        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput);
        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);
      }

      // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
      // Autocomplete.
      AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupClickListener = function(id, mode) {
        var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
        var me = this;
        radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
          me.travelMode = mode;
          me.route();
        });
      };

      AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(autocomplete, mode) {
        var me = this;
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.place_id) {
            window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
            return;
          }
          if (mode === 'ORIG') {
            me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
          } else {
            me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
          }
          me.route();
        });

      };

      AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
        if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
          return;
        }
        var me = this;

        this.directionsService.route({
          origin: {'placeId': this.originPlaceId},
          destination: {'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId},
          travelMode: this.travelMode
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      };

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=your_api_key&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
this.directionsService.route({
      origin: {'placeId': this.originPlaceId},
      destination: {'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId},
      travelMode: this.travelMode
    }, function(response, status) {
```

In destination substitude with a LatLng:

```
destination: {lat: 25.116810, lng: 55.123562}
```

and you can erase input for destination or any event associated to get this field from user.

Answer (score 2):

1. set the desired destination (hard code it)

```
destination: new google.maps.LatLng(25.116810, 55.123562);
```

2. remove the autocomplete associated with the destination

Note that for some reason your destination doesn't work for walking directions, so you may want to remove the travelMode selection.

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: {
      lat: 25.116810,
      lng: 55.123562
    },
    zoom: 13
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.116810, 55.123562)
  });
  new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
}

/**
 * @constructor
 */
function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
  this.map = map;
  this.originPlaceId = null;
  this.travelMode = 'DRIVING';
  var originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
  this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    originInput, {
      placeIdOnly: true
    });

  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
}

// Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
// Autocomplete.
AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupClickListener = function(id, mode) {
  var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
  var me = this;
  radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    me.travelMode = mode;
    me.route();
  });
};

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(autocomplete, mode) {
  var me = this;
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.place_id) {
      window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
      return;
    }
    me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
    me.route();
  });
};

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
  if (!this.originPlaceId) {
    return;
  }
  var me = this;
  this.directionsService.route({
    origin: {
      'placeId': this.originPlaceId
    },
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(25.116810, 55.123562),
    travelMode: this.travelMode
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
};
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#origin-input,
#destination-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
}

#origin-input:focus,
#destination-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#mode-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#mode-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Place Autocomplete</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter an origin location">

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```